# Show Firefox tab tooltips faster

Tags: firefox, tabs, firefox-addon

How can I make the tootip/flyover of the tabs appear faster? There is too much reaction time, it takes ages to look through many of them.

I have most of the time 100 tabs open in Firefox (I am using the tab mix plus addon - "tmp").

To see what's in the different browser windows I do not activate them, but I just move the mouse over the tabs.

After some milliseconds a tooltip/flyover appears (a little box at the mouse pointer is drawn above everything below) and it contains information from the header of the web page that belongs to the tab. But there is a pause of some milliseconds before they are shown.

If there is not a specific about:config variable I would also be interested how to change firefox code (as I assume this is not built into tmp, I didn't find it in the options)

I do not use the tmp feature "select tab by pointing after xxx ms", which could probably interfere.

Thank You

Karl

Answer (score 14):

It may not really be a system wide problem as some others are claiming. For my website, I noticed that tooltip delay in Firefox was much higher than in Chrome. So I researched a bit, and fortunately it's easy to fix.

Just open your about:config in Firefox, and right click, New->Integer value. Give this name to the preference: 
**ui.tooltipDelay**

Give it the value you like, I've just set that to 100 and it works nice now (Their default value is 500).

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Preference_reference/ui.tooltipDelay

Comment: Works in firefox 66.0a1. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The tooltip delay variable isn't in Firefox's about:config because it is a system-wide variable. 
If you are using OS X you can change it using these commands in terminal:

```
// make the change global (applies to all apps)
defaults write -g NSInitialToolTipDelay -int 500 

// just for firefox
defaults write org.mozilla.firefox NSInitialToolTipDelay -int 500
```

I don't know how this can be done under windows. (maybe a registry key or something

EDIT: I just found [this](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx) / [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TweakUI). Maybe you can give it a try?

Comment: Thank you, it is really an insight for me that this setting is system-wide. If no one tells me the registry setting I will have to install the powertoys/tweakui, although I'd prefer to do it myself

Comment: @andi: I think there's some problem with Firefox at least. My link tooltips show up very fast for Chrome, but take around a second in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [Tweak UI](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx) from Microsoft PowerToys has a setting to change this on Windows.  Look for the download on the right of the page about halfway down.